# Typesetting math with postscript / pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, mathjax, postscript

I would like to programmatically generate a PDF file with math equations in it.
I'm considering using high level library such as [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) or using low level PostScript for this task. I have zero experience with both.

The first thing I would like to do in order to test the feasibility of this whole idea is to generate a simple pdf file with a math equation in it.

I'll be happy to get some pointers about how this can be done with either PostScript or PDFBox (or any other Java library), also, is it possible to do that using the exact same fonts that [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) uses ?

The final goal is to take a DOM content and generate a PDF that looks exactly the same.

Thank you

Gilad

Comment: PDFBox is a low level library. I.e. you'll have to need in advance what font to pick and where to place the glyphs. See some examples here https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you for the comment, it helps. Do you know if it is possible to use OTF fonts using PDFBox, and if so, is there a simple example of how to do that ?

Comment: Probably not, I've never seen an example for otf. TrueType and Type1 fonts are supported.

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. The answer is *Computers and Typesetting* by Donald Knuth, v1-4. Pragmatically, I'd suggest trying to use MathJax.